# Breeze - Writing complex query with multiple parameters from client

Tags: sql, entity-framework, breeze

I am trying to write a Breeze query for the Northwind database to show orders that contain all three products that a user specifies. So if a user selects ProductID 41, 51, and 65 from drop downs, the query would return order id 10250.

This is just a sample scenario that I am looking to base another query on in a project I am working on, but I thought using Northwind to explain it would be easier than describing the project. I can easily do it in T-SQL using derived tables, but I need to get the parameters from the client. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just use breeze Predicates - http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/Predicate.html - check out the `and()` sample for how to compound them

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But if I do something like: 
      var p1 = breeze.Predicate("Product.ProductID", "==", 41);
      var p2 = breeze.Predicate("Product.ProductID", "==", 51);
      var p3 = breeze.Predicate("Product.ProductID", "==", 65);
      var newPred = p1.and(p2, p3);
      var query = EntityQuery.from('Order_Details')
                  .select('Order.OrderID')
                  .where(newPred);

Comment: I don't get any results.  Isn't it checking to see if a row has productid 41, 51, and 65? Normall, I would use derived tables in SQL like :
SELECT O.OrderID
  FROM Orders O
  JOIN (SELECT OrderID FROM OrderDetails 
 WHERE ProductID = 41) A ON A.OrderID = O.OrderID
  JOIN (SELECT OrderID FROM OrderDetails 
 WHERE ProductID = 51) B ON B.OrderID = O.OrderID
  JOIN (SELECT OrderID FROM OrderDetails 
 WHERE ProductID = 65) C ON C.OrderID = O.OrderID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're still interested in doing this on the client, you can try the following Breeze query.

```
var listOfProductIds = [41, 51, 65];
var preds = listOfProductIds.map(function (id) {
    return Predicate.create("OrderDetails", "any", "ProductID", "==", id);
});
var whereClause = Predicate.and(preds);
var query = EntityQuery.from('Orders').where(whereClause);
```

This will retrieve all Orders that have **at least all 3 of the Products specified**.

To further filter this so you have all Orders that have **only all 3 of the Products specified**, you can write,

```
entityManager.executeQuery(query)
  .then(filterOrders);

//once you get results on the client
function filterOrders(data) {
    var allOrders = data.results;
    var filteredOrders = allOrders.filter(function (o) {
        return o.OrderDetails.length == listOfProductIds.length;
    });
}
```

You can only filter on the client since OData doesn't yet support the Aggregate Count function like Linq to Entities does. This is probably not ideal but it's an option if you decide not to do it on the server.

Comment: A solution to do a server-side aggregation queryable using the OData protocol is to implement the web service using the `QueryByCube` LINQ extension method provided by the [AdaptiveLINQ](http://www.adaptivelinq.com) component. Disclaimer: I'm the AdaptiveLINQ developer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry in my comment I said look at the `and()` method but in actuality for your use you needed to look at the `or()` method -

```
var p1 = breeze.Predicate("Product.ProductID", "==", 41);
var p2 = breeze.Predicate("Product.ProductID", "==", 51);
var p3 = breeze.Predicate("Product.ProductID", "==", 65);
var newPred = breeze.Predicate.or(p1, p2, p3);

var query = EntityQuery.from('Order_Details').select('Order.OrderID').where(newPred);
```

The only issue with these queries on the client is that depending on how you are building them client-side and how many predicates you are adding they can get *very* long in some situations, such as `select all 200 records except 1 id` type queries which can bite you on IE8.

Comment: Thanks. While that does give me results including the order id I was looking for, it also returns order ids like 10264 that only have one of the products requested. The tricky part is that I need only orders with all three products. It seems like it can be done in linq, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710957/how-to-simulate-derived-table-with-linq-to-entities) but I'd really like to use Breeze in this project.

Comment: The linq example in the other question shows only with a single id AFAICT, so I am not sure the best approach to use here besides to mention that you can always use `withParameters()` on your query and pass an array of Id's to a server method that can run a more complex query on the server if you needed to.  Maybe one of the IdeaBlade guys can chime in with a better answer : )

Comment: Hmm... withParameters to a stored proc in SQL is an interesting idea. I'll give that a shot. Thanks for talking this out with me. I'll let you know if I can get it working that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EntityQuery.withParameters method to call a server side query that has your linq query. i.e. something like this.

```
// On the client
var query = EntityQuery.from("GetOrdersWithProductIds")
        .withParameters({ productIds: [41, 51, 65] });

// On the server
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Order> GetOrdersWithProductIds([FromUri] int[] productIds) {
  return ContextProvider.Context.Orders.Where(... your linq query here ...); 
}
```

or you might try using the support for 'any'/'all' query operators. i.e. something like this.

```
 var predicate = breeze.Predicate("ProductID", "==", 41)
    .or("ProductID", "==", 51)
    .or("ProductID", "==", 65);
 var query = EntityQuery.from("Orders")
       .where("OrderDetails", "all", predicate)
```

Comment: Thanks, but same thing when I use the any/all option. I still get all orders with any of those three products. I'm looking into the with Parameters option to a stored proc in SQL. Having some trouble finding the syntax, but it looks like that is my best bet.